# Apply terraform changes to selected resources only

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform module that creates a couple dozen servers on an ESXi host, based on a template image.

Now, when running `terraform apply` it always wants to replace *all* servers at once. Is there any way to selectively apply changes, similar to Ansible's `-l` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-target` option.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting?in=terraform/state&utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS

`terraform apply -target="aws_instance.my_vm"`